# Why is problemsPathCoordinate vector of a vector of a pair empty?

Tags: c++11

I have tried to fill a smaller vector of a vector of pairs with some contents from a bigger vector of a vector of pairs without success. Below is the relevant code with couts and their output. Hopefully this is detailed enough.

```
    /*******************Problems Occur*****************/

        int iFirst=problemsStartAt;//first index to copy
        int iLast=problemsEndAt-1;//last index -1, 11th stays
        int iLen=iLast-iFirst;//10-8=2
        //if(problemsStartAt!=0)//I.a
        if(problemsStartAt!=0&&problemsEndAt!=0)//I.b
        {
            v_problem_temp=allPathCoordinates[problemsStartAt];
            cout<<"266:"<<v_problem_temp.size()<<endl;
            cout<<"267:"<<allPathCoordinates.at(1).size()<<endl;
            for(vector<pair<int,int>>::iterator  it2=v_problem_temp.begin();
            it2!=v_problem_temp.end();
            ++it2)
                {
                    apair=*it2;
                    point[apair.first][apair.second]=Yellow;
                    cout<<apair.first<<","<<apair.second<<endl;
                }
                problemsPathCoordinate.resize(iLen);
                cout<<"iLen*sizeof(problemsPathCoordinate):"      <<iLen*sizeof(problemsPathCoordinate)<<endl;


                    memcpy(&problemsPathCoordinate[0],&allPathCoordinates[iFirst],iLen*sizeof(problemsPathCoordinate));
        cout<<"279:problemsPathCoordinate.size():"<<problemsPathCoordinate.size()<<endl;

        problemsPathCoordinate.resize(iLen);
        memcpy(&problemsPathCoordinate[0],&allPathCoordinates[iFirst],iLen*sizeof(problemsPathCoordinate));
        cout<<"283:problemsPathCoordinate.size():"<<problemsPathCoordinate[0].size()<<endl;
        cout<<"284:problemsPathCoordinate.size():"<<problemsPathCoordinate[1].size()<<endl;

        cout<<"286:allPathCoordinates.size():"<<allPathCoordinates.size()<<endl;
        cout<<"287:allPathCoordinates.size():"<<allPathCoordinates.size()<<endl;
        //from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35265577/c-reverse-a-smaller-range-in-a-vector


}
    Output:
    759: path NOT full-filled, number: 8
    755: Problems START here at:8
    759: path NOT full-filled, number: 9
    700: Problems END here at: 11
    266:0
    267:0
    iLen*sizeof(problemsPathCoordinate):72
    279:problemsPathCoordinate.size():3
    283:problemsPathCoordinate.size():0
    284:problemsPathCoordinate.size():0
    286:allPathCoordinates.size():79512
    287:allPathCoordinates.size():79512
    time:39 seconds
```

Why are the three problemsPathCoordinate elements empty. How to fix it?
Bo

Comment: `sizeof(problemsPathCoordinate)` is not at all the same thing as `problemsPathCoordinate.size()`. The former has no bearing on the number of elements in `problemsPathCoordinate` container, nor the size in bytes of those elements.

Comment: Copying non-trivial objects (like `vector`) around with `memcpy` exhibits undefined behavior.  Use assignment, or `std::copy`.

Comment: I tried using erase() function like what you see below as a possible substitute for my first question. I am sorry to say that it doesn't work either:

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It would even be more useful to me if you would be so kind and use the code I have delivered to show me how to fix it with copy or an assignment. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

for (vector< vector > >::iterator it = allPathCoordinates.begin(); it != allPathCoordinates.end(); ++it)
    {
        allPathCoordinates.erase(allPathCoordinates.begin()+5,allPathCoordinates.end()-2);
        v_temp = *it;
        //cout<<"v_temp.size():"<

```
    for (vector<pair<int,int> >::iterator it2 = v_temp.begin(); it2 != v_temp.end(); ++it2) {
        //v_temp.erase(v_temp.begin()+2);
        apair = *it2;
        //cout << "(" << apair.first << "," << apair.second << ") ; ";
        openPoints[apair.first][apair.second]=0;
        closedPoints[apair.first][apair.second]=1;
        allObstacles[apair.first][apair.second]=Wall;
        point[apair.first][apair.second]=Yellow;
    }
    /
```